# Convert 'set' object to back to its queryset object

Tags: python, django

```
b = Blog.objects.all()
c= Blog2.objects.all()
a= set(b+c)
```

Now type(a) is 'set' object

I want to convert back it into class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'.

Comment: You can't: a `QuerySet` is not an explicit collection, it is in essence an immutable query in construction, that sometimes caches the object. It looks however very strange to define two models `Blog` and `Blog2`.

Comment: it's not code its just small example code i created for asking. All i want to know is it possible to convert set object back to object.

Comment: taht does not matter, you can not wrap a set in a `QuerySet`. What should that do if you for example then call `.prefetch_related('...')`? Or `.annotate(..)`?

Comment: If both query sets are for the **same model**, you can combine them using `.union()` since QuerySets are sets themselves. But you cannot do this for different models of course, a QuerySet always just returns one model.

Comment: Your `set(b+c)` is actually a `TypeError` you cannot use the "+" operator on QuerySets for different objects. Show us code that actually works.

Comment: I got objects from diff function which may be Duplicated. To remove Duplicate i used set function that worked but it changed to set obj.

Comment: @ChandarKumar: you can use `distinct()` for that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct